# How does the happen-before property relate to visibility and ordering?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

I'd like some clarity on what exactly the happens-before property means.

I've seen explanations for the happens-before property say that updates to global variables (which are not volatile or enclosed in a sync block) are made visible to other threads if they are altered before some other variable which is volatile or altered within a sync block. Is this right? If so, where in the java documentation does it say this?

My understanding was that the happens-before property defines the relationship between shared fields and code execution e.g:

- an unlock of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock of the same monitor.
- a write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same field.
- a call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread.
- all actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join on that thread.

For example:

```
class Shared {

  private int y = 0;
  private volatile int x = 0;

  public void setOne() {
    y = 1;
    x = 1;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

}
```

For the code above, given 2 threads:

```
Shared shared = new Shared();

new Thread(() -> shared.setOne()).start();
new Thread(() -> shared.getY()).start();
```

*Edit*
Assuming we can guarantee that the first thread has started, would getY() return 0 or 1 here?

I've also seen examples saying that this behavior happens only following a read of a volatile field in a thread. So in that case if one thread reads the value of the volatile field (let's say thread B), then all fields written before that volatile field in thread A are available to thread B. According this, if I modify the getY() method in Shared object from above to be:

```
  public int getXPlusY() {
    int local = x;
    return local + y;
  }
```

Is it this action that makes y visible to the other thread?

Comment: Watch this, answer to all of your questions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS5dPQwgnYo

Comment: "Would getY() return 0 or 1 here?" Either. There's no guarantee that the first thread has started by the time the second thread starts.

Comment: Thanks @Shadov, I'll give that a watch.

Comment: @AndyTurner, for the sake of the example let's say we can guarantee that the first thread has started, could it still be either? I'll edit the question to add that assumption. Thanks.

Comment: the Thread being started does not mean that it is executed up to the end before any other Thread can be (partly) executed. Even having a `Thread.yield()` at start of `getY()` it will eventually return zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your second example first.

```
class Shared {

  private int y = 0;
  private volatile int x = 0;

  public void setOne() {
    y = 1; //(1)
    x = 1; //(2)
  }

  public int getXPlusY() {
    int local = x; //(3)
    return local + y; //(4)
  }
}
```

We know that there is a *happens-before* relationship between (1) and (2) due to *program order*:

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

Since `x` is volatile, we know that there's a *happens-before* relationship between (2) and (3)

> A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

And there is a *happens-before* relationship between (3) and (4) due to *program order* again:

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

Therefore, we have a *happens-before* chain (1) → (2), (2) → (3), (3) → (4)

And since *happens-before* is a transitive relation (if A happens before B and B happens before C, then A happens before C) that means that **(1) has a *happens-before* relation with (4)**.

Now let's look at the first example:

```
class Shared {

  private int y = 0;
  private volatile int x = 0;

  public void setOne() {
    y = 1; //(1)
    x = 1; //(2)
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y; //(3)
  }
}
```

There's again a *happens-before* relation between (1) and (2), but that's about it. Since `x` is not read by the second thread, we have no *happens-before* between (2) and (3). Therefore we have **no *happens-before* relation between (1) and (3)**.

The quotes were taken from [Chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)

Comment: 1+, good answer. small addition is that if `x` would not be `volatile`, i.e.: `private int y = 0;
  private int x = 0;` there is the "program order rule" and as such `hb(x,y)`. But that does not mean that they will execute in that order. The _perceivable_ order of the execution is going to be like that, but they might totally execute in a reverse order, if the instructions would allow that: and in this case, method `setOne` does allow that.

Comment: and one more nitpick is that the second example works correctly because of this part [of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4), specifically: _A write to a volatile variable v synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order)_. In much simpler words: an _observed_ volatile write (a volatile read that some thread saw), guarantees that everything that was done before that write, will be visible to the reading thread.

Comment: @Eugene Regarding your second comment - The part you quoted from the JLS requires a read to have *happens-before*: `synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v`. In the second example `getY()` doesn't read `x`, so the is no guarantee about the value of `y`. So while this code *can* work, it's not guaranteed to.

Comment: @Eugene And about the first comment - you're right, but the actual order of execution doesn't matter. The discussion here is about the visibility of the effects of these actions. Regarding the specific code in question, I don't think that the compiler can reorder `1` and `2` precisely due to the effect of the volatile read.

Comment: I don't know if you do that on purpose, but you answer to the question and comments in reverse, both to the initial answer and to my comments. My first comment was targeted towards OP's first example: `class Shared {

  private int y = 0;
  private volatile int x = 0;

  public void setOne() {
    y = 1; //(1)
    x = 1; //(2)
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y; //(3)
  }
}`, where I said _if_ `x` would not be volatile..., as such the part where you responded with _...due to the effect of the volatile read_ makes no sense in this context, really. My entire argument was

Comment: about the precondition that `x is not volatile`. That should clear the confusion for both of us, I hope. `IFF` on the other hand, `x` _IS_ volatile, then of course you are right, such re-ordering would be prohibited. Now my second comment was done in regards to the OPs second example: `class Shared {

  private int y = 0;
  private volatile int x = 0;

  public void setOne() {
    y = 1; //(1)
    x = 1; //(2)
  }

  public int getXPlusY() {
    int local = x; //(3)
    return local + y; //(4)
  }
}`

Comment: and now that I have read you answer again, I don't think that you are correct. You are guaranteed to return `2` from `getXPlusY` only when you have observed `int local = x;` to be `1` in the reading thread. You have no guarantees that this _read_ was not done in between the two writes of : `y = 1; x = 1;`

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, we got the order wrong. In my answer I explained the second example first, so when you said "the second example works correctly", I thought that you were talking about my second example, OP's first.

Comment: @Eugene I agree that we can't know what value `getXPlusY` will return, it depends on the order of execution. Where did I say otherwise? We just know that if we read `x` in `getXPlusY`, then the value of both `x` and `y` reflect the most recent writes. Therefore `getXPlusY` could never see `x` being equal to 1 and `y` being equal to `0`. However other options are possible: x=0, y=0, or x=0, y=1, or x=1, y=1

Comment: @Eugene If you'd like to continue this discussion, I propose we do it in a chat to avoid cluttering the comments. Although I feel like we mostly understand and agree with each other at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I'll rename the classes to make it clear:

```
class First {

    private int y = 0;
    private volatile int x = 0;

    public void setOne() {
       y = 1;
       x = 1;
    }

    public int getY() {
       return y;
    }

}
```

And you pre-condition that:

> Assuming we can guarantee that the first thread has started

There are zero guarantees that `getY` will return `1`. Updates to a shared field are guaranteed to be visible to some reading thread only when you respect the happens-before rules of the JLS, none are enforced here. As such getting a `0` from `getY` is perfectly valid.

Your second example:

```
class Second {

    private int y = 0;
    private volatile int x = 0;

    public void setOne() {
       y = 1;
       x = 1;
    }

    public int getXPlusY() {
       int local = x;
       return local + y;
    }

}
```

again with the pre-condition that:

> Assuming we can guarantee that the first thread has started

is **NOT** guaranteed to return `2`. For that method to output `2`, the reading thread must observe (see) the volatile write.  That is it has to be something along these lines:

```
 public int getXPlusY() {
   int local = x;
   if(local == 1){ // you need to see the write that was done in the other thread
      return local + y;
   }
   return local + y;    
}
```

if you enter that if statement `f(local == 1)` you have observed the volatile write that was done in the other thread (`x = 1`) and, as such, you are guaranteed that everything that was done before that write is visible also. That means that at this point in time, `y = 1`, for sure, so your method will return `2`.

Without this if statement, your read `int local = x` is a racy read, there is nothing stopping this thread to do `int local = x` in between the two:

```
y = 1;
x = 1;
```

---

It turns out this is provable also, here is a `jcstress` test that proves the other answer (at least 1/2 of it) wrong:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450777/how-does-the-happen-before-property-relate-to-visibility-and-ordering
@JCStressTest
@State
@Outcome(id = "0", expect = Expect.FORBIDDEN, desc = "can not happen")
@Outcome(id = "1", expect = Expect.FORBIDDEN, desc = "can not happen")
@Outcome(id = "2", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "reader thread was done before writer did anything")
@Outcome(id = "3", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING, desc = "racy read!!!")
@Outcome(id = "4", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "reader thread sees everything that writer did")
public class VolatileRace {

    // change defaults so that "readerThread" does not output a false positive.
    // it can happen when it runs it's entire method body before "writerThread"
    // does anything at all.
    private int y = 1;
    private volatile int x = 1;

    @Actor
    public void writerThread() {
        y = 2;
        x = 2;
    }

    @Actor
    public void readerThread(I_Result result) {
        int local = x;
        result.r1 = local + y;
    }

}
```

The point of this test is that, it has such an output:

```
  0             0                FORBIDDEN  can not happen
  1             0                FORBIDDEN  can not happen
  2     4,616,926               ACCEPTABLE  reader thread was done before writer did anything
  3         6,694   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING  racy read!!!
  4     3,107,831               ACCEPTABLE  reader thread sees everything that writer did
```

Even if you don't understand it, it shows that the reading thread has seen `3` as its result, that means it has read `x = 1` and `y = 2`.